# How do shell remove the first file/folder of list pattern with pairs of almost identical name

Tags: bash, sed, grep, filesystems, batch-processing

How do Bash shell remove the first ie. earlier file/folder of list pattern with pairs of almost identical name such illustration;
(the real is not directly from ls but it's result from pipe)

```
$ ls

aaa
aab
bbb
bbc
mmm
mmn
xxx
xxy
```

just illustration: ls  | rm  ...?  ... finally to get

```
$ ls
aaa
bbb
mmm
xxx
```

how ?

Comment: By way of illustration only: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I understood: You would like the following to be removed from your list:

- "*pairs of almost identical name*": Judging from your example, this is true when the first character is identical

Here's a one-liner that works in bash:

```
ls | while read -r txt; do printf "% 40s:" "${txt:1}"; echo ${txt:0:1}; done | uniq --skip-chars 41 | sed -e 's/ *\(\S*\):\(.\)/\2\1/'
```

EDIT: I first misunderstood that the OP wants to *delete* the files/folders that are considered to have "*almost identical names*". Here is my corrected one-liner"

```
ls | tee >(uniq --check-chars 1) | sort | uniq -u  | xargs rm -v -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial one for bash. It uses a Levenshtein distance implementation available here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Bash for computing the edit distance between consecutive dir entries and by setting a proper threshold value it can be modified to delete latter entry if it's close enough to previous entry (as-is it won't delete anything).

This will of course lead to problems or questions, for example if you have files `aaa`, `bbb` and `aac` or `caa`. Edit distance of `aac` and `caa` compared to `aaa` is the same but the existance of file `bbb` changes the removal behaviour. Play around with it, it won't remove anything as-is and maybe it works for you or raises requirements you didn't think of.

```
#!/bin/bash
function levenshtein {
    if [ "$#" -ne "2" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 word1 word2" >&2
    elif [ "${#1}" -lt "${#2}" ]; then
        levenshtein "$2" "$1"
    else
        local str1len=$((${#1}))
        local str2len=$((${#2}))
        local d i j
        for i in $(seq 0 $(((str1len+1)*(str2len+1)))); do
            d[i]=0
        done
        for i in $(seq 0 $((str1len))); do
            d[$((i+0*str1len))]=$i
        done
        for j in $(seq 0 $((str2len))); do
            d[$((0+j*(str1len+1)))]=$j
        done

        for j in $(seq 1 $((str2len))); do
            for i in $(seq 1 $((str1len))); do
                [ "${1:i-1:1}" = "${2:j-1:1}" ] && local cost=0 || local cost=1
                local del=$((d[(i-1)+str1len*j]+1))
                local ins=$((d[i+str1len*(j-1)]+1))
                local alt=$((d[(i-1)+str1len*(j-1)]+cost))
                d[i+str1len*j]=$(echo -e "$del\n$ins\n$alt" | sort -n | head -1)
            done
        done
        echo ${d[str1len+str1len*(str2len)]}
    fi
}

for f in "$PWD/"*                  
do
    ret=$(levenshtein "$p" "$f")
    if [[ ret -le 1 ]]              # threshold here is 1 edit
    then
        echo rm "$f"
    else
        echo leave "$f"
    fi
    p="$f"                          # store current entry for next round
done
```

Here is an output of a sample run:

```
$ cd /home/james/test
$ bash ../test.sh
leave /home/james/test/aaa
rm /home/james/test/aab
leave /home/james/test/bbb
rm /home/james/test/bbc
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 'N;/^((.*).)\n\2.$/s//rm \1/p' file
```

Read the file two lines at a time.

If the first file/line is identical except for its last character to the following file/line, create a script to remove it.

Study the output and if it meets requirements, then:

```
sed -En 'N;/^((.*).)\n\2.$/s//rm \1/p' file | sh
```

or:

```
sed -En 'N;/^((.*).)\n\2.$/s//rm \1/e' file
```